# Does rspec capybara support testing against different drivers such as ie?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, rspec, capybara

In selenium I can run firefox, chrome and internetExplorer drivers.

Can I do that with rspec capybara ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use **selenium** as webdriver instead of the default `:rack_test`, and then you can decide with which browser.

in your rspec_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara.register_driver :ie do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :ie)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :ie
```

I don't think you can use a specific broswer with other web driver like rack_test, Capybara-webkit or poltergeist.

**Note**: for chrome you have to download the *chromeDriver* to use it for your test. I think you have to do the same think with ie.

**Update**: here you can find the driver for IE https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support a lot of different browsers. You can check them here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers

Also, you can edit the drivers configuration to adapt to your necessities.
 For example, if you are using `webkit` but you don't want the `qt` warning messages appear in the console, you can set your browser to `webkit_with_qt_plugin_messages_suppressed`